# UWP can't build with EF core 3.1

Tags: c#, uwp, entity-framework-core

I have a existing UWP Application. When I upgrade to EF Core 3.1 I get the following build error:

```
error APPX1101: Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'e_sqlite3.dll'. Source files: 
error APPX1101: C:\Users\ninop\.nuget\packages\sqlitepclraw.lib.e_sqlite3\2.0.2\runtimes\win10-x86\nativeassets\uap10.0\e_sqlite3.dll
error APPX1101: C:\Users\ninop\.nuget\packages\sqlitepclraw.lib.e_sqlite3.v140\1.1.2\runtimes\win10-x86\native\e_sqlite3.dll
```

I tried to delete the .nuget cache and restarting VS but without success. Also the issue occurs on multiple computers. Also reinstalling EF Core didn't help.

EDIT:
My Application has Target Version 1903 and Min Version 16299

Also tried deleting bin and obj folder and chaning the build platform afterwards, but without success.

EDIT2: For reference here is the source code with the related branch: https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyFox.Windows/tree/update-nugets

Comment: Hi, what is the minimum version of your UWP application? You can try to delete the `bin` and `obj` folders inside the project, and try to build again after switching the target build platform (such as switch x86 to x64).

Comment: thanks for your reply @RichardZhang-MSFT. I updated my post. Unfortunately it didn't work so far.

Comment: Hi, I tried to create a new project with a minimum version of 16299 and installed the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` (all version are 3.1) nuget packages, but I couldn't reproduce the problem. Do you have other nuget packages installed? If you revert the package to a previous version, will this issue still occur?

Comment: I have other nugets, but as far as I know nothing with EF. Based on the message I suspect that it doesn't have anything to do with the Xamarin Projects in my solution. Also when I go back it works again.

Comment: For reference I added the link to the GitHub Repository

Comment: Hi, I downloaded the code example you provided and reproduced the problem. It is speculated that there may be a nuget package that references sqlite (an implicit reference), which conflicts with the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` package you are currently using, causing duplicate references. If there are no special functional requirements, it is recommended to keep the original package version reference

Comment: Thanks for your effort! to what original package do you refer? I tried to add the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core` but that doesn't change anything and is missing the `Batteries_V2`.
I also tried `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` but this is is lacking the `UseSQLite` call.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. I tested your code and although it reproduced the error, I couldn't infer which nuget package caused it. It may be that there is a conflict in the reference between the package and the package, which leads to duplicate references of `e_sqlite3.dll`. `keep the original package version reference` means not to upgrade `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` until we find the nuget package that caused the problem

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I made several tests, but so far wasn't able to get it working with just the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`. I'm actually not sure if that is even possible. Wouldn't that lack all concrete logic to actually access a concrete database? I'm in the untderstanding that this is in the DataBase Providers.

Comment: Hi, We have received some other reports. At present, there are some compatibility issues between the UWP and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1` versions, which are not currently available. It is currently recommended that you still use version 2.2.6 of `EFCore`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the AppCenter package:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19156

I could resolve the issue by removing the AppCenter Nuget from my UWP Project.